# 1px gap of absolute positioned element with transform: translate on Safari only

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions, css-position

There is a full width container that contains inner box which are centered inside the container. There is a 100% width absolute positioned box inside the box. To the box also applied transform: translate().

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cover-holder">
    <div class="cover">
        <div class="cover__overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cover-holder {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cover {
  width: 206px;
  height: 206px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-self: center;
}

.cover__overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 50%, 0);
}

.cover:hover .cover__overlay {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

**Problem:**

On odd sizes of window there is appeared 1px gap (or transparent "border") on Safari browser only:

[image: safari]

**Expected result (how it looks on Chrome, Firefox and IE):**

[image]

[Demo in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/milax/sqpuc9qc/7/)

Comment: What Safari version are you using, and can you give a specific pixel range of window width/height that you see the border showing up for? I'm looking at Safari 10.1.1, and I'm resizing the result panel of your fiddle to all kinds of sizes, but I don't ever see a border show up.

Comment: Hi @cjl750 I tried different: real device - Safari 10.11.6 on OS X El Capitan, and on BrowserStack  - Safari 9.1 on El Capitan and Safari 10.1 on Sierra. Regarding window size you can easily notice the issue with resizing window...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, switching between using just `transform` instead of `transform3d` fixed it for me.